# React infinite scroll interseption observe fetch data problema

Tags: javascript, reactjs

tengo un problema quiero hacer un infinite scroll, para mis tarjetas random y las tarjetas que tengo al usar un filtro de busqueda, estoy usando el api de intersection observe para hacer una nueva peticion, pero al hacer unas dos o tres el servidor se muere y ya no me devuelve nada, tambien me pasa que a veces no me regresa todas las tarjetas, antes de escribir este codigo si funcionaba bien, otra cosa que me pasa es que al hacer la peticion, la constante limite se dispara muchas veces, trayendome hasta 30 cartas de golpe, no se que estoy haciendo mal,
gracias por la ayuda

mi sadbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-varahamihira-cw6p6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Hay que elaborar un poco el objetivo, pues no esta claro. Parece que quieres ir mostrando las tarjetas en la misma página, cada que se haga scroll en 10, se pide por las otras 10 y asi hasta terminar de navegar por todas ellas. ¿Puedes confirmar?

Comment: Hola, si asi es, eso es lo que intento lograr